# keeping rows with NA value in data.table r

Tags: r, data.table

I want to keep only this rows in the table which has at least NA value in specific columns. I need solution which will work with with various number of columns.

I have code like this:

```
library(data.table)
cols<-c("colname1","colname2")
DT<-DT[rowSums(is.na(DT[,cols,with=F])) == 2]
```

And I'm getting such error with this code:

> Error in DT[, c("colname1", "colname2"), with = F] :
>       incorrect number of dimensions

Could anyone help me with this issue?

---

I find the right solution, but i still don't know why the first one doesn't work.

```
cols<-c("colname1","colname2")    
DT<-DT[eval(rowSums(is.na(DT[,cols,with=F])) == length(cols))]
```

Could anybody tell me why my firs code doesn't work?

Comment: are you trying to remove rows where both of the columns show NA or when either of them show NA individually?

Comment: i want to keep only this rows which has NA in both columns.

Comment: changed my answer to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

you should just be able to do this:

**Keeping only rows where both equal NA**

```
DT <- DT[(is.na("colname1") == T & is.na("colname2") == T), ]
```

Comment: I have updated question becouse this is not exactly what I am looking for.